# Ajax code with error that I cannot locate

Tags: php, ajax

I have a Ajax code snippet that has a bug that I cannot find.
The code worked a while back perfectly but now I cannot locate it, all seems to be correct.

I have tried to check my db codes, all good.
Tried to eliminate excessive code to bring it to basics, no result.
I have a text line that say "there are reviews" yet they are not shown. I have no MariaDB errors visible.

pagination_parser.php in directory 'includes'

```
<?php
// Make the script run only if there is a page number posted to this script
if(isset($_POST['pn'])){
    $rpp = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST['rpp']);
    $last = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST['last']);
    $pn = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST['pn']);
    // This makes sure the page number isn't below 1, or more than our $last page
    if ($pn < 1) {
        $pn = 1;
    } else if ($pn > $last) {
        $pn = $last;
    }
    // Connect to our database here
    require("db_connect.inc.php");
    // This sets the range of rows to query for the chosen $pn
    $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pn - 1) * $rpp .',' .$rpp;
    // This is your query again, it is for grabbing just one page worth of rows by applying $limit
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE status='1' ORDER BY reg_date DESC $limit";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $dataString = '';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $stars = $row["stars"];
        $comment = $row["review"];
        $itemdate = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["reg_date"]));
        $dataString .= $stars.'|'.$comment.'|'.$itemdate.'||';
    }
    // Close your database connection
    mysqli_close($db_conx);
    // Echo the results back to Ajax
    return $dataString;
    exit();
}
?>
```

index.php in folder 'texts'

```
<?php
// Connect to our database here
require "../includes/db_connect.inc.php";
    // Create connection
$db_conx = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if ($db_conx->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db_conx->connect_error);
}
// This first query is just to get the total count of rows
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM review WHERE status='1'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
// Here we have the total row count
$total_rows = $row[0];
// Specify how many results per page
$rpp = 5;
// This tells us the page number of our last page
$last = ceil($total_rows/$rpp);
// This makes sure $last cannot be less than 1
if($last < 1){
    $last = 1;
}
// Close the database connection
mysqli_close($db_conx);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var rpp = <?php echo $rpp; ?>; // results per page
var last = <?php echo $last; ?>; // last page number
function request_page(pn){
    var results_box = document.getElementById("results_box");
    var pagination_controls = document.getElementById("pagination_controls");
    results_box.innerHTML = "loading results ...";
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("POST", "pagination_parser.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var dataArray = hr.responseText.split("||");
            var html_output = "";
            for(i = 0; i < dataArray.length - 1; i++){
                var itemArray = dataArray[i].split("|");
                html_output += "stars: "+itemArray[0]+" - date "+itemArray[2]+" - comment <b>"+itemArray[1]+"</b><hr>";
            }
            results_box.innerHTML = html_output;
        }
    }
    hr.send("rpp="+rpp+"&last="+last+"&pn="+pn);
    // Change the pagination controls
    var paginationCtrls = "";
    // Only if there is more than 1 page worth of results give the user pagination controls
    if(last != 1){
        if (pn > 1) {
            paginationCtrls += '<button onclick="request_page('+(pn-1)+')">&lt;</button>';
        }
        paginationCtrls += ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <b>Page '+pn+' of '+last+'</b> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
        if (pn != last) {
            paginationCtrls += '<button onclick="request_page('+(pn+1)+')">&gt;</button>';
        }
    }
    pagination_controls.innerHTML = paginationCtrls;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pagination_controls"></div>
<div id="results_box"></div>
<script> request_page(1); </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I do expect to have the html table with data, but just get the "loading results ..." .. but no data.
And mysql user and settings are checked, mysql direct query works fine, but I just don't get it on my development site.
I use development subsection to find bugs, but here I am about to give in.
My Ajax knowledge is just not good enough. Oh, it's not real ajax but XMLHttpRequest code.
Wouldn't mind to update to proper Ajax.

Comment: Original code I used and modified to suit my needs from here:http://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Ajax-Pagination-Tutorial-PHP-MySQL-Database-Results-Paged

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple mistake to me:

```
// Echo the results back to Ajax
return $dataString;
```

`return` will not echo your result like the comment says. Use one of the following:

1. `echo` construct:

```
echo $dataString;
exit();
```

2. `print` construct

```
print $dataString;
exit();
```

3. `die` function:

```
die($dataString);
```

4. `exit` function:

```
exit($dataString);
```

Comment: Thank you for your input.
But nothing made a difference.
I'm thinking it's my db connection that is causing all this. 
But, that didn't give me any errors ...

Comment: Check the browser console (network tab) if the AJAX request is actually sent and what's the response status and body. Looks like JS expects HTTP response status 200 to replace the "loading results ...", so there might be some error on PHP side, which results in HTTP status 500.

Comment: Thats it.
I was looking for the pagination_parser.php file in the same folder, where it is not!
So updating the path and it works as intended !
I was sure I had it checked ... I stand corrected.
Thank you for your assistance.